# Before filter syntax difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is the difference between these two clips of code? The first clip is labeled "This one:" and the second clip is labeled "And this:". (.rb)

```
class Reseller < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :blah, :blah, :contact_email
```

This one:

```
before_save { |reseller| reseller.contact_email = contact_email.downcase }
```

And this:

```
before_save { contact_email.downcase }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sets the value *back* to the persisted property (or at least it should; I'd double check).

The second just downcases it and does nothing with the result.

If the second read `contact_email.downcase!` then it should modify the actual property.

- http://apidock.com/ruby/String/downcase
- http://apidock.com/ruby/String/downcase%21

The "bang" method follows the Ruby convention of naming destructive methods, e.g., methods that alter underlying data, with a trailing `!`.

**Note:** As tadman points out, you'd need to vet this against your AR tests to make sure your app still functions as expected, since it may bypass some of AR's magic.

Comment: Doing in-place modifications on ActiveRecord attributes is probably risky as it messes up dirty tracking. As far as ActiveRecord's concerned, nothing changed. Generally, you're right, though, in-place modifications are better.

Comment: @tadman Agreed--I'd be pretty nervous about this if all of AR is being used.

Comment: Won't the second case throw `NoMethodError`? `self` in block is `Reseller` class.

Comment: It's possible that the block binding is shifted to the instance, but I'm not sure how this behaves in Rails 3 vs. Rails 4.

Comment: @MarekLipka Hmm, that's possible--perhaps I spoke too soon.

Answer (score 3):

The first downcases the contact email and saves it, though it's not clear if that will actually work as specified. The second one creates a temporary value that's discarded and doesn't do anything useful.

Generally you implement these like:

```
 class Reseller < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :downcase_contact_email

 protected
   def downcase_contact_email
     self.contact_email = self.contact_email.downcase if (self.contact_email?)
   end
 end
```

I've added protection there to only call the `downcase` method if `contact_email` is actually present. There's a risk your `before_save` could trigger on a `nil` value as it's not clear if you have any validations here.

As a matter of style, clean-up methods like this are typically triggered `before_validation` where you have a chance to validate that it's populated correctly. In the `before_save` phase, it's too late to catch any problems and aborting the save is something you do as an absolute last-resort.